# $L^\infty$-bounds on eigenfunctions of Laplace-Beltrami opeator

Tags: differential-geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, manifolds, eigenfunctions

Let $w_k$ be the eigenfunctions of the Laplace-Beltrami operator on a compact manifold $M$ without boundary. We assume that $\{w_k\}$ are orthonormal, thus $\|w_k \|_{L^2} = 1$.

We know $w_k$ are smooth functions. Is such a bound true:
$$\lVert w_k \rVert_{L^\infty(M)} \leq C$$
for all $k$? i.e. are all the eigenfunctions bounded above p/w a.e. by a single constant? Can we remove the a.e. part?

In 1D domains the eigenfunctions are sine and cosine functions which are nice of course.

Comment: Are you assuming these eigenfunctions have some specific scaling (like the one that makes them orthonormal)? Otherwise, the question isn't well-defined: since continuous functions on a compact manifold are bounded, you can just rescaled them all to make this work (or, indeed, to not work).

Comment: @Chappers Yes let us take the eigenfunctions to be orthonormal with respect to the $L^2$ inner product.

Comment: I suspect such a bound is _not_ true in general, but I don't know of a counterexample. I think a Sobolev inequality should give a bound roughly of the form $||w||_{L^\infty} \leq C \lambda^{n/4} ||w||_{L^2}$, where $n$ is the dimension and $w$ is an eigenfunction with eigenvalue $\lambda$. This does not rule out that the eigenfunctions may grow pointwise as the eigenvalue increases. Coming up with an example to show this is sharp is another question.

Comment: The first few sentences in this paper of Toth and Zelditch state that the $L^\infty$ norm of the $L^2$-normalized $\lambda$-eigenfunction is $O(\lambda^{(n-1)/4})$, and that the round sphere shows that this is sharp. Their main theorem is that under a completely integrable geodesic flow assumption, the manifolds with uniformly bounded eigenfunctions are flat.
https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0002038

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the question is no. I'm going to share some interesting things I learned from:

- Toth and Zelditch, Riemannian Manifolds with Uniformly Bounded Eigenfunctions: https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0002038
- Garrett, Harmonic Analysis on Spheres, I: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_c/spheres_I.pdf - 
  This is a nice set of notes building the theory of spherical harmonics in an interesting way.

Toth and Zelditch prove a theorem of the form: Under a "completely integrable geodesic flow assumption", if there is a uniform $L^\infty$-bound on all $L^2$-normalized eigenfunctions, then $(M, g)$ is flat. (This is outside my area of expertise and I have not attempted to understand the assumption or to read their proof.)

*Remark:* The statement "there exists an orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions with uniformly bounded $L^\infty$-norm" is strictly weaker than "there is a uniform bound on the $L^\infty$-norm that applies to every orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions". For example, on the torus $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$, the former is true, but not the latter.

**Claim:** Let $E_\lambda$ be the $\lambda$-eigenspace. There exists $w \in E_\lambda$ such that
\begin{align*}
\frac{||w||_{L^\infty}}{||w||_{L^2}} \geq \sqrt{\frac{\dim E_\lambda}{\operatorname{volume}(M)}}.
\end{align*}

**Corollary:** If there exists a sequence of eigenvalues of unbounded multiplicity, then there exists a sequence of $L^2$-normalized eigenfunctions with unbounded $L^\infty$-norm.

Note that the standard torus and the standard sphere both have a sequence of eigenvalues of unbounded multiplicity.

*Proof of Claim:* For $x \in M$, consider this functional on $E_\lambda$: $f \in E_\lambda \mapsto f(x) \in \mathbb{C}$. By the Riesz representation theorem, there exists $F_x \in E_\lambda$ such that for every $f \in E_\lambda$, $f(x) = \langle f, F_x \rangle$.

In particular, $F_x(x) = \langle F_x, F_x \rangle = ||F_x||_{L^2}^2$,
so $||F_x||_{L^2} = \sqrt{F_x(x)}$ and
\begin{equation} \tag{$\ast$} \label{ineq}
\frac{||F_x||_{L^\infty}}{||F_x||_{L^2}} \geq \frac{F_x(x)}{||F_x||_{L^2}} \geq ||F_x||_{L^2} = \sqrt{F_x(x)},
\end{equation}
and this holds for every $x \in M$. (We'll try to find $x_0$ where $F_{x_0}(x_0)$ is large.)

Let $\{w_i\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $E_\lambda$. Expand $F_x$ in terms of the basis: $F_x = \sum_i \langle F_x, w_i \rangle w_i = \sum_i \overline{w_i(x)} w_i$. Now evaluate at $x$:
\begin{align*}
F_x(x) = \sum_i \overline{w_i(x)} w_i(x) = \sum_i | w_i(x)|^2.
\end{align*}
Integrate over $M$:
\begin{align*}
\int_M F_x(x)\, \operatorname{dvol}(x) &= \sum_i \int_M | w_i(x)|^2 \operatorname{dvol}(x)  \\ 
&= \sum_i 1 \\
&= \dim E_\lambda.
\end{align*}
Thus there exists $x_0 \in M$ such that $F_{x_0}(x_0) \geq \dim E_\lambda/\operatorname{volume}(M)$. Using \eqref{ineq}, this shows that
\begin{align*}
\frac{||F_{x_0}||_{L^\infty}}{||F_{x_0}||_{L^2}} \geq \sqrt{\frac{\dim E_\lambda}{\operatorname{volume}(M)}}.
\end{align*}

*End Proof of Claim.*

*Remark:* There's nothing special about $E_\lambda$, and in fact we could replace $E_\lambda$ by the span of any finite set of continuous functions.

Comment: Note that while the statement on the orthonormal basis is strictly weaker, the stronger statement may hold. For example, on a torus defined from an irrational lattice, multiplicity is bounded so that eigenfunctions are uniformly bounded.