# Spherical harmonics of order $l$ with smallest $L_\infty$ norm

Tags: differential-geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, manifolds, eigenfunctions

Let ${\mathbb H}_l$ be a space of spherical harmonics of order $l$, i.e.
$${\mathbb H}_l = \{f: {\mathbb S}^{n-1}\to {\mathbb R} \mid \Delta_{{\mathbb S}^{n-1}}f=-l(l+n-2)f\},$$
where $\Delta_{{\mathbb S}^{n-1}}$ is Laplace-Beltrami operator.

It is known that if $\|f\|_{L_2({\mathbb S}^{n-1})}=1$, then $\|f\|_{L_\infty({\mathbb S}^{n-1})}\leq \sqrt{\frac{N(n,l)}{\omega_{n-1}}}$, where $N(n,k) = {\rm dim}({\mathbb H}_l)$ and $\omega_{n-1}$ is the surface volume of ${\mathbb S}^{n-1}$. Moreover,
$$\sup_{f\in {\mathbb H}_l: \|f\|_{L_2({\mathbb S}^{n-1})}=1}\|f\|_{L_\infty({\mathbb S}^{n-1})}=\sqrt{\frac{N(n,l)}{\omega_{n-1}}}.$$
Details can be found at [$L^\infty$-bounds on eigenfunctions of Laplace-Beltrami opeator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336488/l-infty-bounds-on-eigenfunctions-of-laplace-beltrami-opeator) .

Is there any known upper bounds on $$\inf_{f\in {\mathbb H}_l: \|f\|_{L_2({\mathbb S}^{n-1})}=1}\|f\|_{L_\infty({\mathbb S}^{n-1})},$$ i.e. how small supremum norm of harmonics of order $l$ can be?

Comment: Yes, but I suppose that inf is substantially smaller than sup.

Comment: That is a non trivial statement! Do you have any evidence?

Comment: Oops, I was thinking about something else.